# Angular2: image load event is missed when using bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl

Tags: angular

I am using bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl in DomSanitizer to ge the link of the image without any security added prefixes, and I am using load event on the image to decide when to stop the spinner indicating the image is loading.

Before I started using bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl everything was fine, after i used it I noticed that load event is missed, I removed bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl and the event is caught again.

```
<img [src]='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(project.url)'  (load)="onLoad()">
```

is this expected?

Any help or explanation of whats really happening is much appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm this is behavior as well. Just removed the sanitizer and it works as expected. We should probably file a bug for this.